# Creating a div with two inner div. Background / Content must "follow"

Tags: html, background, height

How can I make like this:

[ DIV-1 ]

[ DIV -2]
    SIDE MENU INSIDE 2
   [/ DIV - 2]

[ DIV -3]
    MAIN CONTENT INSIDE 3
   [/ DIV -3]

[/ DIV-1 ]

So, let's say that DIV 3 is having a really **long** content - much more than DIV 2.

How can I do so the background and border etc of DIV 2 is following the height of DIV 3?

For now I have tried with the 980.css grid, although it did not work.

This is what I have now:

```
        <div class="column grid_12">

                <div class="column grid_3" style="background-color:gray;">
                MENU!
                </div>
                <div class="column grid_8" style="background-color:black;">
                CONTENT!    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

            </div>

        </div>




</div><!-- End Row -->
```

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use JavaScript and set the height of DIV2 to the height of DIV3.

Like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var MyHeight = $('.grid_3').height();
   $('.grid_8').height(MyHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second column will always be longer than the first, you can use something like the following example:

```
<html>
<head>

    <style>
        .container {overflow:hidden; position:relative;}
        .col1 {position:absolute; width:200px; height:100%; top:0px; left:0px; background:#ffbebe;}
        .col2 {width:400px; margin:0px 0px 0px 200px; background:#ffff00;}
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="col1" >
           MENU!<br />
        </div>

        <div class="col2" >
            CONTENT!<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best -and easiest - bet is to use [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like the equal height columns from www.ejeliot.com

I've set an example up on JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/s8uLG/1/

You set your container up with overflow set to hidden, then on each div add negative margin-bottom and equal positive padding-bottom.

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
#container div { float: left; background: #ccc; width: 200px; margin-bottom: -2000px; padding-bottom: 2000px; }
#container .col2 { background: #eee; }

<div id="container">
   <div>
        <p>Content 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
   </div>
   <div>
        <p>Content 3</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Faux Columns is also good and probably easier to set up but if you're really dead against using an image this is a pretty good method.